# How to resolve [dbo].[SP_NAME] contains an unresolved reference to an object in Sql Server Database Project?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools, database-project

I am trying to create SQL Server Database Project (SQL 2012, VS 2013 .net v4.6) for our existing database. I created the project, imported the schema, and now ran into this issue. I am getting the error below:

*Error  SQL71501: Procedure: [dbo].[StoredProc_Name] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [dbo].[TABLE1].[TABLE_ALIAS]::[COL1], [dbo].[TABLE1].[COL1] or [dbo].[TABLE1].[TABLE_ALIAS]::[COL1]. D:\SPNAME.sql*

I know a fix, but that doesn't make sense to me. Instead of using an alias, if I use two part naming convention then the error is resolved.

```
--errors when referenced using alias
SELECT T.* 
FROM [dbo].[TABLE1] AS T (NOLOCK)
WHERE T.COL1 = @COL1

--no errors when using 2 part naming convention
SELECT T.* 
FROM [dbo].[TABLE1] AS T (NOLOCK)
WHERE [dbo].[TABLE1].COL1 = @COL1
```

I would love understand why is this happening? I very much doubt the issue is with using alias, is it? So to get this thing building do I need to replace the use of alias in all of our sps with two part naming convention? That's too difficult to be a solution... I did come across questions talking about similar issue and the resolution offered was to change to 2 part naming convention, which is quite not scalable in my case. Any alternative ideas?

Comment: I definitely have used aliases in this way in SSDT - it might be because it's expecting to see `WITH(NOLOCK)` instead of __just__ `(NOLOCK)`?  Or doesn't like the `AS`?

Comment: @DanField - just tried that and it didn't help. After you confirmed having used alias, I looked up some sps in the project and I could see bunch of my sps not having any issues with a similar approach, and other bunch getting this error...

Comment: You have two issues in here. First is you are using NOLOCK. Do you know what hint really does? It is much more than just dirty reads. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ If you are going to use query hints (which I would suggest you don't) you need to include the WITH keyword. Omitting is deprecated. Then you seem to be using the sp_ prefix for procedure names. This is bad for a number of reasons. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: Could you provide some actual code that causes this error?  I suspect that your alterations may have led to missing something here..

Comment: @SeanLange - thanks for pointing out that nolock thing, I will do more research and make adjustment on that. As for 'sp_name', I was trying to refer to 'storedproc_name' (sp=storedproc), no we are not using sp prefix. I updated the question.

Comment: @dan - I don't think I can include the real table names, but it is just as simple as listed in the post, in couple of stored procs with issues, that 'col1' is the primary key.

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer. As others mentioned, this should just work. The only time I've seen issues with that particular warning is when you do have an ambiguous column reference (multi-table query with the same column name in several tables and not specified properly). Stale views/procs don't help the matter when you're trying to clean things up. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other members suggested, that is a valid syntax. I just wanted to share why it was erroring out for me. The reason I was getting an error was because of the stale stored proc. When I imported the schema, I got these stored proc, but the column name had been changed in the current schema and these stored proc were not updated. Since my primary goal was to get this project building for now, I commented the 'where' clause and moved on. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of SSDT you are using? I tried the same statement using the latest SSDT update and it is supported without the same issue. You can download the latest SSDT update from [SSDT Preview update for VS 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674919.aspx)

SSDT preview update currently has the most up-to-date support. It is marked as preview since it supports SQL Server 2016 CTPs but for SQL Server 2012, it should provide a RTM level stability.